# Приём данных из сокета в char*

Tags: c++, visual-c++, char

Вот WinSock ф-ия для приёма данных из сокета:

```
int recv(
  SOCKET s,
  char *buf,
  int len,
  int flags
);
```

Данные пишутся в `char*`. Итак, сокет должен принять картинку jpg, видимо придётся её сначала записать в `char*`. Но в принимаемых данных есть байт `00`, который воспринимается `char*` как конец строки, поэтому полностью принять данные не получается. Что делать?

## UPD

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <iostream>

void main(){
    char ch[]="           "; 
    ch[0]='q';
    ch[1]=(char)0x00;
    ch[2]='e';
    
    std::cout << ch << "\n";

    system("pause"); 
};
```

Как ни странно, эта программа выведет только символ q

Comment: Каким образом нулевой байт мешает вам принять картинку?

Comment: @IronVbif, в дебаг режиме приём (и соссна сам char*) обрывается как раз в том месте, где в jpg файле впервые встречается 00

Comment: Что значит обрывается? У вас бинарные данные длины N (то что вернуло recv). Накопите нужное количество (весь jpg) и отдайте дальше, например в файл.

Comment: @IronVbif, как параметр len в ф-ию было передано значение заведомо больше размера принимаемых данных, тоесть принять должно за один вызов и возвращает ровно размер jpg - 66101 байт, при последующих вызовах данных больше нет - всегда возвращает 0 и пустую строку. То есть всё, что удаётся принять- это несколько байт jpg до байта 00

Comment: Все что удалось принять записано в буфере. Если вы говорите что в recv вернул 66101, значит он столько принял и они там. То, что в данных 0 ничего не меняет, он не обрывает буфер.

Comment: @IronVbif, смотрите UPD. Всё дело в символе

Comment: @IronVbif, мб дело в потоке? мб он просто останавливается на символе конца строки? Если да, то как тогда вывести всю строку?

Comment: бинарные данные выводятся вот так 
    std::cout.write(ch, sizeof(ch)) << std::endl;